# Cells not in Numerical sequence in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pandas

I have a file in Jupyter notebook but for some reason the cell numbering is not in order (e.g 1,2,3,4).

In my file it starts at 1, then 89, then 44:

[image: Screenshot of file]

##### Does anyone know how to get them in sequential order?

Comment: Why do you want them in numerical order? The order is simply the order of executed cells. So if you run all cells (e.g., up to cell 100) and you run cell one again, that will become 101. This has no implications whatsoever for your programming, AFAIK.

Comment: You can restart your kernel, and run all cells. Then they will be executed in order

Comment: Thank you, will I lose all variables though if I restart?

Comment: yes. See my answer for the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers you are referring to are there to show the order in which your cells have been executed. Consider this example:

[image]

If you want these numbers to be in order, by definition it means that you have to execute all your cells in order.

- If you want them to start from 1, restart your kernel:

[image]

or:

[image]

- You can either execute all your cells manually, or click on the button "Run all cells":

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. This solves my issue. It just makes it look neater in presentation

Answer (score 0):

The numbers have no importance. They are the order at which you ran them.
As suggested above - do `Kernel | Restart` and this will reset the numbers.